# Add Ant variable in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

i added variable to ant Runtime : window > preferences > Ant > Runtime > in classpath tab i selected "Ant home entries (Default)" and i used add variable ... button.

so i added EXTDIRS variable.
To test it i wrote this build.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Ant-Test" default="main" basedir=".">
 <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
 <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->

 <property name="extd" value="${EXTDIRS}" />

 <echo message="${EXTDIRS}"></echo>
```

The problem that Ant can't see the variable and print this on the console :

```
 Buildfile: /home/amira/workspace/AntTutorial/build.xml
      [echo] ${EXTDIRS}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a value in the `Classpath` tab only changes the class path used for Ant, it does **not** set a property in Ant.

Look at the `Properties` tab and add a property which uses the variable you defined.